# Алгоритм покрытия площади уголками

Tags: алгоритм

**Необходимо найти все возможные варианты покрытия**

*Уголки только такого типа (3 квадрата):*

[image: уголок 1]
[image: уголок 2]

[image: уголок 3]
[image: уголок 4]

Площадь которую нужно покрыть может быть любым прямоугольником m на n клеток без одной произвольной клетки **(с условием, что хотя бы один вариант покрытия имеется)**.

*Пример площади для заполнения:*

[image: площадь заполненная уголками]

Площадь, которую необходимо покрыть, имеет габариты m+n не больше 20 и ограничение по времени примерно 1,5-2 секунды, поэтому перебор в лоб не подходит

Comment: Какие-нибудь наработки есть уже? :)

Comment: Произвольным - не может: покройте, например, 4x5...

Comment: @harry, дополнил: с условием, что хотя бы один вариант покрытия имеется

Comment: @madhattermonroe , пока идей хватает только на перебор всех возможных вариантов .. но это слишком долго по исполнению. Скорее всего есть какая-нибудь закономерность которую я к сожалению не вижу

Comment: ну вообще-то не больше 20 как раз намекает на полный перебор. Состояний поля не больше 2^20. Что около 1кк. Как раз влазит. Ну пересчёт пусть ещё операций 20.

Comment: Для степеней двойки решается в полпинка... В общем виде пока не соображу, как.

Comment: @Harry вообще каноничное решение - динамика по профилю. это чуть-чуть сложнее задачи про паркет. Но тут просто перебора хватит.

Comment: @pavel Я в геометрии слаб еще со школы :( Так что, откровенно говоря, даже не представляю, как тут перебор делается. Кстати, был бы очень признателен - посмотреть на практике, как его реализовать.

Comment: *это чуть-чуть сложнее задачи про паркет* Ничем не сложнее. До заключительного этапа - мостим плашками 2*3 (состоит из 2 фигур), получая в остатке 2*2 (1 квадрат в остатке), 2*3 (без остатка) либо 2*4 (2 квадрата в остатке).

Comment: @Harry лобовой перебор что-то типо такого https://ideone.com/WeT0UF могут быть мелкие баги, но идея такая)

Comment: и да, те кто пишут конструктивную идею - тут надо не замостить, а число способов посчитать. И да, задача чуть сложнее задачи про паркет. В паркете просто xor, тут более сложная формула, а ещё и пересчёт.

Comment: @pavel Откровенно говоря, по исходнику идею так и не понял :(, но не хочется вас грузить и просить разжевывать... Что-то мне ничего лучше, чем в каждую свободную точку ставить новую фигуру грубо 3*4 способами (точка+ориентация) и смотреть, не перекрывается ли, в голову не приходит. Но это - ветвление с отсечениями... А полный перебор - вообще не понимаю, как его можно организовать? Нет же конкретных мест, где да/нет...

Comment: @Harry ну собственно именно это в коде и есть. Мне пояснить за код не тяжело. По факту мы ищем первую пустую позицию и пытаемся запихать туда 1 из 4 вариантов (всего 4 их). Дальше рекурсивный спуск. А чем полный перебор от ветвления с отсечением отличается? P.S. для ускорения достаточно использовать любое кеширование.

Comment: Что-то мне кажется, что тут нужно использовать *бинарные диаграммы решений* - их Кнут в томе 4А описывает, но как с ними работать - это не ко мне :(

Comment: @pavel Разве всего 4 варианта? Их 12 - я вот на бумажке только что  нарисовал все, - все разные по отношению к точке...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72040/discussion-between-pavel-and-harry).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эффективное решение этой задачи использует динамику по профилю (и радуйтесь что не по рваному краю). Пример тут http://e-maxx.ru/algo/profile_dynamics но нужно немного доработать.

Однако ограничения не больше 20 сумма очень маленькие, поэтому можно сделать в лоб.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int N = 8;
const int M = 8;
char pos[N][M];

int rec(int x,int y, int d){
    Omega++;
  if (y == M-1){
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<M;i++)
      s+=!pos[i][y];
    return s+d <=1; //all ok;  
  } 
  if (pos[x][y])
    return rec((x+1)%N,y + (x+1)/N,d);
  int res = 0;
  if (!d)
    res+=rec((x+1)%N,y + (x+1)/N,1); //empty
  // #
  //##
  if (x != N-1 && !pos[x+1][y] && !pos[x+1][y+1]){
    pos[x][y] = 1;
    pos[x+1][y] = 1;
    pos[x+1][y+1] = 1;
    res+=rec(x+1,y,d);
    pos[x][y] = 0;
    pos[x+1][y] = 0;
    pos[x+1][y+1] = 0;      
  }
  //#
  //##
  if (x != N-1 && !pos[x+1][y] && !pos[x][y+1]){
    pos[x][y] = 1;
    pos[x+1][y] = 1;
    pos[x][y+1] = 1;
    res+=rec(x+1,y,d);
    pos[x][y] = 0;
    pos[x+1][y] = 0;
    pos[x][y+1] = 0;        
  }
  //##
  //#
  if (x != N-1 && !pos[x+1][y+1] && !pos[x][y+1]){
    pos[x][y] = 1;
    pos[x+1][y+1] = 1;
    pos[x][y+1] = 1;
    res+=rec(x+1,y,d);
    pos[x][y] = 0;
    pos[x+1][y+1] = 0;
    pos[x][y+1] = 0;        
  }
  //##
  // #
  if (x != 0 && !pos[x-1][y+1] && !pos[x][y+1]){
    pos[x][y] = 1;
    pos[x-1][y+1] = 1;
    pos[x][y+1] = 1;
    res+=rec( (x+1)%N,y + (x+1)/N,d);
    pos[x][y] = 0;
    pos[x-1][y+1] = 0;
    pos[x][y+1] = 0;        
  } 
  return res;
}

int main() {
  cout << rec(0,0,0)<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

По коду всё просто. Мы будем пытаться заполнить самую левую нижнюю (или как вам удобнее представлять порядок операций) пустую клетку. Если всего 5 вариантов что с ней делать. Перебираем рекурсивно каждый из них.

P.S. чтобы уложиться в 1 секунду нужно добавить любую меморизацию (или убрать рекурсию и переписать на циклы). Это нужно, т.к. взять любой прямоугольник 2*3 и там будет 2 способа. Рассматривать их отдельно не имеет смысла, но сильно замедляет работу. Без этого 10 на 10 будет работать порядка 8 секунд.

Comment: не очень понял где в коде идёт исключение квадрата из площади

Comment: @danilashrainer `return s+d <=1` т.е. или полное покрытие (2*3 например прямоугольник) или 1 квадрат пустой.